# Using XBox controller on Windows 10 (Far Cry 4)

Tags: pc, controllers, xbox-one, windows-10

My question may sound simple but I've been struggling since a long time and I have no idea why it is so difficult.

I have a wireless XBox controller, I have no problem pairing it with my laptop.
Then I open Far Cry 4 and it seems the buttons Y X A B have been replacing the left stick even though I'm not so sure about that. The rest of the buttons have no effect whatsoever, and sometimes virtually no buttons are doing anything.

I've been trying to download many software/drivers but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a a Xbox One controller USB cable. Connect your controller and PC to the USB and see if that works. If not, something might be physically wrong with the controller. Try other controllers if you can.